# C# - Add to stuff to each textbox line till a specific character

Tags: c#, regex

So, I'm working on a code beautifier and I need some help.

When there's an opening bracket `{` I want every line after that to have 4 spaces in front of them till the closing bracket `}`. I've managed to do it for the line after with `string.Replace("{", "{" + Environment.NewLine + "    ")`, but that's not enough.

Also how would I got about handling semicolons `;`, because sometimes they have a space after them and sometimes not. I can do this: `string.Replace(";", ";" + Environment.NewLine`, but when there's a space after the semicolon the space moves to the second line so it looks bad, I can check for `;` and `; *space*` and replace both, but then it creates an empty line if there is a space.

Thanks for the help, idk if my explanation was understandable, but I hope you know what I mean :D

Comment: Any reason you want to do this yourself rather than using one of the existing ones? There's a *lot* more to writing a decent code formatter than just scanning until you find a brace etc. (Think about braces in comments and string literals, for example.)

Comment: This is probably not something that can be accomplished in an offhand way. Reasonably, one has to consider strings and comments...

Answer (score 1):

You will need a nesting counter so you will introduce 4 spaces at the beginning as many times as it is indicated in the nesting counter.

You should increase the counter each time you find the character '{' and decrease it when you find '}'. Also, I'd make sure those curved brackets are not surrounded by quotes so they are actual code and they don't belong to some string.

About the semicolons, you should just try:
`Regex regex = new Regex(";\\s*");
regex.Replace(string, ";" + Environment.NewLine);`

Comment: What's the relevance of  `^` ?

Comment: ^ is the Regex symbol for the beginning of the input. In this case it would be the beginning of the textbox line.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get you re using regex by your text. You might want to show regex examples of the _`counter`_ word in context.

Comment: Hi, you are right, it was pretty confusing, I was just exemplifying a way to insert 4 spaces at the beginning of the string but there are many ways and mine wasn't very obvious. I have also fixed the example about the semicolons, it was mixing regex and standard string replace. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, try something like this:

```
while(!lines[i].Contains("}")) {
    lines[i].Insert(0,"    ");
    i++;
}
```

If you want to handle more than one level of curly braces you could do something like this:

```
int level;
for(int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++) {
    if(lines[i].Contains("{") level++;
    if(lines[i].Contains("}") level--;
    for(int j = 0; j < level; j++) lines[i].Insert(0, "    ");
}
```

For your second question, I believe it is a problem with the order of your operations. If you replace semicolon by semicolon + line break alone you will carry the space to the next line. If you replace the semicolon + space for semicolon + line break and then the semicolon for semicolon + line break you will have double lines. What you want to do is to replace semicolon + space for semicolon (namely remove all of the spaces) and then replace semicolon for semicolon + break line.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

1. Look for all `;` and make a line break.
2. Delete all trailing spaces.
3. Do the step that Pol suggested.